# Sequential weak star closure in Asplund spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider an Asplund space ($X,\|\cdot\|$). Since $X$ is Asplund, we know that the set
$$
F:= \{ x\in X \mid \|\cdot\| \text{ is differentiable at } x\}
$$
is dense (and thus, non-empty) in the strong topology of $X$. Let
$$
F^* := \{ x^* \in X^* \mid x^* \text{ achieves its norm at some $x$ in $F$}\}.
$$
I have the following questions:

1. Clearly, if $F=X\setminus \{0\}$ then $F^*$ is dense in $X^*$ by the well-known Bishop-Phelps theorem. In the general case, is $F^*$ dense in $X^*$? Or, is it sequentially weak$^*$ dense in $X^*$?
2. Do we have the equality
   $$
   \mathrm{cl}^{{se}^*}(F^* \cap \mathbb{S}^*) = \mathbb{B}^*,
   $$
   with $\mathrm{cl}^{{se}^*}$ stands for the sequentially weak$^*$ closure, while $\mathbb{S}^*$ and $\mathbb{B}^*$ stand for the dual unit sphere and unit ball, respectively, in $X^*$. If not, how can we describe the set $\mathrm{cl}^{{se}^*}(F^* \cap \mathbb{S}^*)$?

Thank you for your help.